# how can we tell dagitty in R to not include a latent variable in the set of all the adjustment sets?

Tags: r, directed-acyclic-graphs, adjustment, causality

I am using dagitty package in R. I have a DAG as follows where U is latent:

```
library(dagitty)
dag <- dagitty("
dag {
U [latent]
U -> Z1
Z1 -> Z2
Z2 -> Y
U -> X
X -> Y
}
")
```

When I call the  `adjustmentSets(x = dag, exposure = "X", outcome = "Y" , type = "all")` function, this is the results:

> {U}
> {Z1}
> {U, Z1}
> {Z2}
> {U, Z2}
> {Z1, Z2}
> {U, Z1, Z2 }

the results include U. How can I not have U in the results without changing the dag?

I expect it to not show U in the results. I tried changing the DAG as follows:

```
dag <- dagitty("
dag {
Z1 -> Z2
Z2 -> Y
Z1 <-> X
X -> Y
}
")
```

And I get the following results which is what I expected:

> {Z1 }
> {Z2 }
> {Z1, Z2 }

But I don't want to manually change the results, as I have a really large graph and I want to get the right results without changing the graph structure.